# python: how to determine default program associated with a given type, under windows

Tags: python, windows

How do I find the program associated with a given file type using Python under Windows?

For example, given http I'd like python to determine the default browser. I can do this from a cmd prompt by running 'ftype http'.  Windows gives me the full path to the browser.

I've tried:

```
subprocess.call(['http://www.google.com'])
```

which results in: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

```
subprocess.check_call(['cmd', 'ftype', 'http'])
```

which launches a cmd window, but doesn't do anything else

Comment: Why don't you just use the webbrowser module? http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html Just call webbrowser.open_new(url), it will use the system default browser on all supported systems (unix, osx, windows)

Comment: That works nicely, +1, but I'd still like an answer to the general question.

Comment: Looking at the source for that, os.startfile() is promising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the '/c' option that configures `cmd` to run a command and then exit:

```
subprocess.check_output(['cmd', '/c', 'ftype http'])
```

Comment: I had tried that too and got WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid

Comment: @foosion: That's strange. It works fine for me. Are you using the Windows console? It probably won't work in a Windows IDE that doesn't have a real stdout file handle.

Comment: very strange.  I'm on Windows XP, but that shouldn't matter. Worse, I just tried running from the python cmd line interpreter, and it returned internet explorer, which is not my default browser.  There appears to be something odd here.

Comment: @foosion: It works for me in the console and also in IDLE, PyScripter, and IEP in Python 2.7.2 and 3.2.2. I think `ftype` returns the value from HKLM\Software\Classes, but you might have a setting in HKCU\Software\Classes that overrides it.

Comment: I'm on 2.7.2.  IDLE gets Error 6, cmd line gets the wrong answer.  At this point, I'm guessing there's some issue with my system.

Comment: @foosion: The command works for me in IDLE if I use idle.bat or click on idle.py or idle.pyw. It also works from the console if I run with `python.exe` or by combining `start` with `pythonw.exe`, i.e. `start \pythonxx\pythonw.exe \pythonxx\lib\idlelib\idle.pyw` (xx is 27/32). But I get the invalid handle error in the latter case if I do not use `start`. Maybe that will help you figure out what's wrong in your config.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print subprocess.check_output(['ftype', 'http'])
```

Comment: WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid